# How does this website disable selection of content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-scraping, copy-paste

I found an interesting website which disables copying of web page content using mysterious technique.

First, it disables mouse right-click. This can be overcome by disabling javascript of browser.

However, even after disabling javascript, the content of web page is still unselectable. I looked into the css of the web page but could not find a clue.

How does it implement the functionality of disabling content copy?

Answer (score 6):

There is a property in CSS called [user-select](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css3_pr_user-select.asp) that you can use to prevent users from highlighting text.

Usually this is used for buttons or objects that you want to interact with (like click-and-drag).

There is also a jQuery UI method [disableSelection](https://api.jqueryui.com/disableSelection/) that will do a similar thing, and you can see it being used throughout the UI API

Note: `disableSelection` is deprecated now since `user-select` is available

You can see that the website you linked has the CSS property on the `html` tag, preventing it site-wide

---

### Update

I've looked through their code and they have multiple more layers to prevent user selection as well, mostly in the Javascript. See the fiddle below for a few examples of how they are blocking selection. There may be more methods being used, but it would take a while to decipher them all; easiest way to bypass them is to install an addon to your browser that will disable any scripts from running, then just disable the CSS blocking you and you've got it. Or just take the easy way out and copy the HTML directly from the inspect element window. As other's have said in the comments, there are multiple ways around them preventing you from opening the devoper tools like `Ctrl + Shift + I` or using the browser's menu.

[Demonstrating Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Renson/t03gs1pw/16/)

Comment: However if you know a little bit of programming, this won't stop you. You can easily press `F12`, go to `elements` and still copy whatever you want. But good approach, didn't know about it, thanks!

Comment: Annoyingly @mindmaster the website also disables right clicking and pressing F12, so I had to load up a different site, open the developer console, then navigate to the site. The site _really_ doesn't want you to copy stuff

Comment: lol, you're right! god damn, that's some previlige stuff right there that you can't copy... well, I was totally wrong then! `F12` doesn't work at all

Comment: @MickelsonMichael you can still open it via the menu of your browser, F12 is just a shortcut. They also repeated the `user-select: none;` all over across the hierarchy :D but i managed to copy with removing the rules and disabling JS too

Comment: @Kaddath Is right! you can access it by doing `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `i`

Comment: It seems collectively we've found a bunch of really simple ways to foil his plans. But I guess that stops the lazy "criminals"?  Nobody will steal Johnn's reviews without at least a _little_ effort

Comment: Site scrappers don't use a GUI web-browser... Such limitations will only make your honest users feel bad, the ones you are trying to protect from won't ever notice...

Comment: You can't stop the iron horse called "dev tools"

Comment: no. The "user-select: none !important;" is crossed out in my firefox, and should not have effect on the text. What does the "!important" mean?

Comment: @William the `!important` tag is a CSS tool to help circumvent CSS specificity rules. See [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception) for more information. Essentially properties marked `!important` will overwrite other matching properties on an element, regardless of their specificity or load order (unless those properties _also_ have an `!important`)

Answer (score 0):

The page is employing the following css, contained in a `<style>` element in the `<head>`:

```
html {
 -webkit-touch-callout:none;
 -webkit-user-select:none;
 -khtml-user-select:none;
 -moz-user-select:none;
 -ms-user-select:none;
 user-select:none;
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)
}
```

Comment: When I disable javascript, reload the webpage, right-click on some text, click "Inspect element", I find the "user-select:none" is crossed out with a yellow question mark saying "invalid property name". This means the user-select property does not apply to the text. I could not find any other property you mentioned that is applied to this element. BTW, "user-select: none !important;" , what does "!important" mean?

Comment: @William, can you tell me which element you are specifically looking at and which version of Firefox you are using?

Comment: @MickelsonMichael, for example, when you right-click the text "Show Posts in" and inspect the element,in the rules view, you'll find the effective user-select is in body, div, p, span {
    cursor: inherit;
    user-select: none !important;
}.  If you de-select the user-select line, you still cannot select text. The user-select declared in the style in the <head> element is not appeared in the rules view. I just upgraded my firefox to 69.0 and the "invalid property name" warning disappears now.

Comment: @William check out the update to my answer for more information. They are using a multitude of methods to prevent user selection including the `user-select` CSS property. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Renson/t03gs1pw/16/) for just a few of the examples

Comment: Thank you,@MickelsonMichael . Although I can copy the HTML directly from the inspect element window, it is not easy to accurately select what I want to copy. I would like to go to the rules view, disable the "use-select" line, then select text directly on the webpage. I wonder why after disabling the "use-select" line, I still cannot select the text.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the text selection in HTML we need to give user-select property value as none.

Answer (score -1):

You can add following line in your CSS

```
body{
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```